# After 16.04 system update boots to black screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, macbook-pro

After installing updates my Ubuntu machine, a MacBook Pro, started booting to a black screen. After researching a bit the cause appears to be [incompatible nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error), which didnt work even after reinstalling as suggested. I initially installed the nvidia drivers to get dual monitors working.

Does anyone know of compatible drivers for nvidia in a macbook pro running 16.04?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution to the black screen was to boot into `Recovery Mode` from GRUB, then select `failsafeX`. `failsafeX` brought up an error "system is running in low graphics mode" the only way to close the error was `ctrl+alt+fn+f1` Then command prompt tries to run, but gets stuck; hitting `ctrl+c` exited this and booted into gui. From there uninstalling nvidia `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` allowed the machine to boot again normally.

However, i now assume dual monitors will be broken again :(